# wide and long table in latex

Tags: latex

I am using a wide and long table. I am not sure how to put it in my thesis. Since it is wide, sidewaystable may be the choice. Meanwhile it is also too long to fit in one page, so longtable comes into my mind. However, I cannot make sidewaystable and longtable working together for one table, e.g.

```
  \begin{sidewaystable}  

  \begin{longtable}{| c ||c| c| c |c| c|| c |c| c|c|c| }  
         \caption{A glance of images.}  
          \centering  

   % table content  

  \end{longtable}  

  \end{sidewaystable}
```

What shall I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`lscape`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/lscape.html) package with `longtable`  or `supertabular`.

Answer (score 2):

use a `p{width}` in place of l,r, or c in your column declaration, like this:

```
\begin{longtable}{ | p{0.2\textwidth} | p{0.5\textwidth | }
```

Then, to keep your content centered, add a `>{\centering}` before the `p{width}`, like this:

```
 \begin{longtable}{ | >{\centering}p{0.2\textwidth} | >{\centering}p{0.5\textwidth | }
```